# How to effectively compare two lists of dictionaries to declare a "winner"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following data in a list of dictionaries. How can I effectively compare these two according to the following rule, and conclude who the winner is?

> if any value in a list turns out to be more than all the other values
>   of the other list , The list with bigger value will be declared the
>   winner

```
s1=[{'link': 0}, {'link': 0}] 
s2=[{'link': 0}, {'link': 1}]
```

My Attempt was :

```
for stat in s2:
    for stat1 in s1:
        if stat['link'] >= stat1['link']:
            print('success')
```

Comment: Are you sure your total ordering is precise enough? "s2 is greater than s1 because one of the values in s2 turns out to be greater than in s1"

Comment: if any value in a list turns out to be more than all the other values of the other list , The list with bigger value will be declared the winner

Comment: Just to be clear: What you are saying is that you do not need to compare element by element. The list with the biggest value is the winner. The description of the question does not reflect this statement. You should update the description of your question.

Comment: Sure Will add that

Comment: To make your description more clear you should write: "One of the values of s2 is greater than ALL the values of s1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see which list has the biggest number, you can use the builtin [max function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
s1=[{'link': 0}, {'link': 0}] 
s2=[{'link': 0}, {'link': 1}]

maxes = max([[item["link"] for item in s1], [item["link"] for item in s2]])

if maxes[0] > maxes[1]:
    print("S1 is greater than S2")
elif maxes[0] < maxes[1]:
    print("S2 is greater than S1")
else:
    print("S1 and S2 are equal")
```

Comment: You probably mean `any`.

Comment: @AustinHastings I think you're right. I was trying to do a neutral comparison because if one element of S1 was greater, and one element of S2 was greater I thought that it shouldn't return that S1 was greater overall, but I guess that's was OP wants.

Comment: This does not match the "s2 is greater than s1 because one of the values in s2 turns out to be greater than in s1"; it

Comment: I updated my answer based on new information OP provided.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you consider the sequencing relevant. Your existing solution would compare every value in s1 against every value in s2.

You probably want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to marry the two sequences together. If you expect the sequences to have different lengths, use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest) instead.

For example:

```
def compare_same_lengths(s1, s2):
    for i1, i2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if i1['link'] < i2['link']:
            return -1
        elif i1['link'] > i2['link']:
            return 1

    return 0
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment:

> if any value in a list turns out to be more than all the other values of the other list , The list with bigger value will be declared the winner

you should probably use `max` and then just compare the two maxima:

```
m1 = max(s1, key=operator.itemgetter('link'))
m2 = max(s2, key=operator.itemgetter('link'))

if m1['link'] > m2['link']:
    return 1
elif m2['link'] < m1['link']:
    return -1
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: It is getting the below error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'"

Comment: @Zuckerberg That's because `m1` and `m2` are the original dictionaries and not the values. Just use `m1['link'] > m2['link']`, etc.

Comment: @AustinHastings -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were trying to break out of the nested loop? In which case, I suggest you wrap your code in a function so you can simply use `return` once you find an element in s2 greater than one in s1.

Anyway, assuming this is the strict definition:

> s2 is greater than s1 because one of the values in s2 turns out to be
>   greater than in s1

One linear solution is to first get the minimum of s1, then iteratively compare that with the elements in s2.

```
def is_greater(s1, s2):
  s1_min = min(s1, key=lambda x: x['link']) # just `min(s1)` works for python 2.7
  for item in s2:
    if item['link'] > s1_min['link']:
      return True
  return False
```

Note that if you have s1 values of [0,1,2,3] and s2 values of [0,1,0,0] that would still result s2 > s1 because at least one of the values in s2 is greater than at least one of the values in s1 (which i think doesn't really make sense as a definition of greater than :P )

EDIT: added key parameter in `min` function

Comment: Thanks, Will this work if s1 and s2 turns out to have different number of elements also ?

Comment: This list with the biggest value wins. This is what the OP wants.

Comment: also min is not supported on a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, this will work if you  have different number of elements in the list. Ah you're right, min is not supported for a list of dictionaries. I'll edit the answer

Comment: This is the error I am getting now :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Ah my bad, I edited the answer again. anyway, I think you should use Austin Hastings' answer since mine did not take into account your comment 

>if any value in a list turns out to be more than all the other values of the other list , The list with bigger value will be declared the winner